# Exact word match Solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solarium

I want to the exact results for my query.

For e.g. when I search "New york" , then it doesn't give me exact results about New York
But it also gives me results like:

"New York"

"New Delhi"

And other cities starting from "New"

So how can I get only results for "New York"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phrase query should do the job. Just put quotes around your query terms.

Comment: can you please give me an example of phrase query?

Answer (score 0):

From your question What i Understand is you want "New York" to be consider as single token ,you can do that by modifying tokenizer for field
Change Tokenizer from **StandardTokenizerFactory** to **KeywordTokenizerFactory** reindex data and query again

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you expect to get as search results, [Stupid Lucene Tricks: Exact Match, Starts With, Ends With](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_leighton_fisher/2012/01/stupid-lucene-tricks-exact-match-starts-with-ends-with.html) might also be worth a look.