# Solr giving weird search results

Tags: solr, lucene

I am getting a weird behavior with Solr search results.
I have a lot of documents indexed with a title field.
When I am doing a search over title field solr is not giving higher scores to exact match.

e.g. if my query is "China"
I am getting top documents with titles:
"China House of China Cove"
"National Art Museum of China"

This is weird as there is a document with title "China" and hence that should be the best match for query. Does anyone know what could be wrong here ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775702/exact-word-match-solr/21791826?noredirect=1#21791826

Visit this Question hopefully you will get the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Second to @sohan for the pointer.  I'd agree it makes better sense to boost the exact match as in your example.  And I hope this might be easier to work around, by indexing the title field again for exact match.

```
 <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <field name="titleExact" type="textExact" indexed="true" stored="true" />
 <copyField source="title" dest="titleExact"/>
```

Above example was taken from this **[article](http://everydaydeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/02/solr-improve-relevancy-by-boosting.html)**, which also provides a nice writeup to solve the problem.